# 0x swap Expected quote.orders to conform to schema /signedOrdersSchema

Tags: 0x

Hi i should like to know if the fonction "swapQuoteConsumer.executeSwapQuoteOrThrowAsync(quote,{opt})" is depreciated in 0x protocol V4 or not ? i have a perdsistent "error Expected quote.orders to conform to schema /signedOrdersSchema" and i don't know where find le schema of "/signedOrdersSchema" thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Swap Quotes

```
 .methods.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [tokenIn, tokenOut]).call((error, amountsOut)         
 => 
{
 if (error) {
  console.log(`Error fetching swap quote: ${error}`);
return;
 }

 const amountOut = amountsOut[1];
 const priceImpact = 0.01; // 1% price impact
 const minAmountOut = amountOut * (1 - priceImpact);
 const swapQuote = {
tokenIn: tokenIn,
tokenOut: tokenOut,
amountIn: amountIn,
amountOutMin: minAmountOut,
deadline: deadline,
fee: fee
};

  import { Order, SignatureType, signatureUtils } from '0x.js';

  // Define the order parameters
 const order: Order = {
 makerAddress: '0x,
 takerAddress: '0x
 feeRecipientAddress: '0x
 senderAddress: '0x
 makerAssetAmount: 
 takerAssetAmount: '
 makerFee: 
 takerFee: 
  expirationTimeSeconds: , // UNIX timestamp 
  salt: 
  makerAssetData: , // token address
  takerAssetData: //  token address
  exchangeAddress: '0x
 chainId: 1
  };

// Sign the order with a private key
const privateKey = '0x
const signature = signatureUtils.ecSignOrder(order, privateKey, 
SignatureType.EthSign);

  // Verify the signature
 const isValidSignature = signatureUtils.isValidOrderSignature(order, signature,  
 privateKey, SignatureType.EthSign);
 if (!isValidSignature) {
  throw new Error('Invalid signature');
  }

  // Convert the order and signature to a signed orders object
  const signedOrders = [{ order, signature }];
```